# Global variable is not recognized inside a procedure in TCL script for ns-2

Tags: global-variables, tcl, ns2

I am trying to run the following tcl script but getting an error in procedure thpt_rec that
ns: thpt_rec: can't read "tcps(0)": no such variable
    while executing
"$tcps(0) set bytes_"
    (procedure "thpt_rec" line 4)
    invoked from within
"thpt_rec"

But when I replace this tcps(0) with a variable named sink at all place everything works well. Kindly shed light in this issue.

```
set ns [new Simulator]  
set tracefile [open tcpf1.tr w]  
set thptfile  [open thpt.tr  w]   
$ns trace-all $tracefile

proc finish {} {  
global ns tracefile thptfile  
$ns flush-trace  
close $tracefile  
close $thptfile  
exit 0  
}

proc thpt_rec {} {  
global ns tcps(0) thptfile  
set time 1.0   
set bw [$tcps(0) set bytes_]  
set now [$ns now]  
puts $thptfile "$now [expr $bw/$time*8/1000000]"  
$tcps(0) set bytes_ 0  
$ns at [expr $now+$time] "thpt_rec"     
}

for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {  
set n($i) [$ns node]  
}

for {set i 0} {$i < 4} {incr i} {  
$ns duplex-link $n($i) $n(4) 10Mb 2ms DropTail  
$ns duplex-link $n(5)  $n([expr ($i+6)]) 10Mb 2ms DropTail   
}

$ns duplex-link $n(4) $n(5) 0.25Mb 10ms DropTail

set tcp(0) [new Agent/TCP]  
$ns attach-agent $n(0) $tcp(0)  
set tcps(0) [new Agent/TCPSink]  
$ns attach-agent $n(6) $tcps(0)  
$ns connect $tcp(0) $tcps(0)  
set ftp(0) [new Application/FTP]     
$ftp(0) attach-agent $tcp(0)  

$ns at 0.0 "thpt_rec"  
for {set i 0} {$i < 1} {incr i} {  
$ns at [expr (5.0 * $i )] "$ftp($i) start"  
$ns at 140.0 "$ftp($i) stop"  
}  
$ns at 150.0 "finish"  

$ns run
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
global ns tcps(0) thptfile
```

with

```
global ns tcps thptfile
```

and it should work OK.

<s>The problem is that the `tcps` variable is an [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl22.html), and *array elements are not variables* — they are just values.</s>  So if you want to access an element of a global array in a procedure, you should declare the array variable itself as `global`.

Comment: Array elements _are_ variables (and can be named in `upvar` commands just fine) but you use `global` on the whole array and not the elements of it.

Comment: @DonalFellows, thanks for your correction. Somehow I forgot that I myself like to do things like `upvar 0 state(name) name` in my programs and up*var* clearly works with variables ;-)